# How to create an Action type class property that accepts a regular and generic types (c#)

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics, delegates

I have a class that needs to be passed a function in its constructor.  I then assign this function to a property on the class. The problem arises in that the function has 3 parameters: 2 strings and 1 generic. Bear in mind the code passing the function is in vb.net and the code that assigns that function to a property is in c#.

```vb
Function myFunc(Of T)(s1 As String, s2 As String, model As T)
```

And I want to pass this function to my class constructor.  In my class I want to have a property that is basically:

```cs
private Action<string, string, T> _myFunc { get; }
```

But this obviously does not work, as there's no way to define T in this propertie's context.

If I ignore the generic, the following works:

```vb
Function myF(s1 As String, s2 As String)

Dim class = New myClass(AddressOf myF)
```

```cs
public class myClass{
    private Action<string,string> _func {get;}
    public myClass(Action<string,string> func){
        _func = func
    }
}
```

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?  I tried obvious things like `Action<T><string,string,T>` but to no avail.

Comment: Either make `T` a type parameter of the class, or just make the parameter `object` instead. What do you hope to achieve by making `T` parameterized? What does it offer in your particular case that `Object` doesn't?

Comment: Not sure - I'm a bit of a noob with generics, I figured there was a good reason that the function was generic type T instead of Object, but maybe not.

Could you give an example of how to make T a type parameter of the class?

Comment: So somebody else defined this function? We need to know more about what the function is for and what the class is for, so we can help you figure out how to satisfy all your requirements in a way that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, the function is essentially a logger, and the model of type T is various different types of Api Responses.

Comment: Do these Api responses share a base class or interface? If so, use that as the type.

Comment: Please do not remove the `<!-- language: ... -->` tags. They make the code easier to read by applying syntax highlighting (word colouring) matching the specified programming language to the code blocks. See the _**Syntax highlighting for code**_ section in the [Markdown and Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more info.

Comment: Ok @djv so basically the answer to the question I asked is no, it is not possible to have a generic type T in an action?

Comment: See what @EdPlunkett said, it is possible if `T` is a type parameter of the class. But if the response classes share some inheritance, barring some other requirement, using the base class / interface as the type would be the way to go.

Comment: Making type T a parameter of the class: `public class MyClass<T> { public MyClass(Action<string,string, T> func) { ... } }` -- but then `T` must be specified at the time you declare a reference to `MyClass<T>`, and it'll only be able to handle actions of that type. That may not be even remotely appropriate for what you're doing.

Comment: The [**`Action<...>` overload**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549392(v=vs.110).aspx) that you use is already declared as `Action<T1, T2, T3>`, it requires **static types**. So yes, the answer is **no** because you can only declare generic types in a method or class declaration, such as: `public class MyClass<T>` (or like in `Function myFunc(Of T)`). The closest to a generic object you will get is to use an `object`, as already suggested.

Comment: `it is not possible to have a generic type T in an action?` no, it is possible. It is not possible to *declare* it there (semantics, maybe, this is what @VisualVincent is talking about). You can declare at class level, and use it in a member i.e. `class myClass<T> { private Action<T> myAction; }`